# power query editor - Replacing values in select columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: replace, powerbi, powerquery

I am working in power query editor. I was hoping someone could help me with replacing values. My real data set contains thousands of rows and upwards of 30 columns, but i have provided a simplified example data set below.

[image: TableTest]

I would like to replace values in multiple columns based on multiple conditions
For this example... I would like to replace the null values in Column2 and Column4 with a zero, ONLY when Row2 = A.
If Row2 does not equal A, then I would like to keep the original value in the cell.

[image: TableResult]

In my data set, I will need to do this for many columns at once (not just two) so I would prefer to have this done in a single step, rather than creating a step for replacing within each column. Thank you!

Edit for clarity: the multiple conditions are...

- The value of Column1- In this example, I said that it must be A. My real data set has six possible values for this column, and I will need to perform replacements on different columns for different values of Column1.
- The columns being replaced- In this example, I said that it must be Column2 and Column4.
- The value of the cell being replaced must be null.

I think I will need to perform 6 separate replacement steps (one for each possible value of Column1)

Comment: What you failed to do is specify what you mean by multiple conditions. Is the next example replacing column 3 and 4 based on 1 and 5 for example, and you want code that does things to any columns based on other columns ?

Comment: Sorry. Column1 has six possible values in my real data set- let's call them A, B, C, D, E, and F. I am okay with creating a new replacement step for each of these six values. My real data set has over 30 columns, but the first condition of the replacement will always relate to Column1. Made-up example: when Column1=A, I need to replace null values with zeros within Column2 and Column4. Then when Column1=B, I need to replace null values with zeros within Column7, Column9, and Column11. Then when Column1=C, I need to replace null values with zeros within Column8, Column20, Column22, and Column23

Comment: thats what I thought. I don't think any of the below will do that without some mods

Comment: See my edit for an approach that should work.

Comment: "...ONLY when Row2 = A. If Row2 does not equal A..." - surely you meant to write _Column1_ rather than _Row2_ - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent comment, try modifying the code below. Merely concatenate appropriate `List.Transform` arguments to the `Record.TransformFields` function for your different changes.

I just used the columns you showed, but the code should be easy to modify for your actual requirements.

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],

//will adjust to any number of columns, assuming columns 2..n are integer types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}} & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1), each {_, Int64.Type})),

//Note we have created a list for the columns to be transformed instead of hard coding each individual column
//In your example, you referred to columns 2 and 4, so I used List.Alternate to refer to the even-numbered columns
//But you can construct the list in many different ways.
    #"Replace nulls" = Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=>
        Record.TransformFields(r, 

            List.Transform({"Column2","Column4"}, 
                each {_, each if r[Column1] = "A" and _ = null then 0 else _})
                
            & List.Transform({"Column3"},
                each {_, each if r[Column1] = "B" and _ = null then 0 else _}))),
            
            
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Replace nulls", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1", type text}} & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1), each {_, Int64.Type}))

in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the power query as below. You can add the column name in "each  List.Contains( {**"Col2","Col3"**}" if you want to apply the changes in other columns

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}, {"Col3", Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers", each [Col1]="A", 0, (x,y,z)=> if y then z else x, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
each  List.Contains( {"Col2","Col3"},_)
)
)
in
    Custom1
```

Comment: Your method is faster. But I think you want `(x,y,z)=>if y and x=null then z else x,` else it will replace everything with "A" in column1, not just the nulls. Also, adding code so that the particular column names do not have to be hard-coded would be helpful to the OP who wrote he had 30+ columns.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue I'm having. When I run the above code, all of the values where column1 is "A" will be replaced. I only want the null values to be replaced. Also, I agree that hard-coding column names would not be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I overlooked the question.   Yes, (x,y,z)=>if y and x=null then z else x should be use.   If there are more than 30 columns, I have update the condition from each List.Contains( {"Col2","Col3"}  to each not contains("Col1"). 
The updated code is shown as below:
---
 Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers", each [Col1]="A", 0, (x,y,z)=>if y and x=null then z else x, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),
each  not List.Contains( {"Col1"},_)
    )
    )
---